# Сравнение скорости для команд оканчивающие цикл: jcxz vs cmp cx, 0 je

Tags: ассемблер, условия, tasm

Добрый день, использую `tasm` (Turbo assembler) и мне стало жутко интересно какая же конструкция работает быстрее :

```
jcxz метка
```

или

```
cmp cx, 0
je метка
```

причем `Vim` не подсвечивает вариант с `jcxz`

Comment: Кроме того, что уже есть в ответе: тут обычная проблема: алгоритмическая оптимизация vs наглядность исходника vs лишний байт-другой vs экономия на спичках vs .... В доисторические времена (когда был актуален 16-битный ассемблер) я чаще использовал именно первый вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вторая конструкция будет дольше выполняться по тактам, следовательно медленнее.

Не зря же команду придумали разработчики архитектуры x86...

Подробности тут:

[Источник](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/60/60/lecture/1782)

Comment: Спасибо, будет на заметку

Comment: ответ могу принять только через 5 мин

Comment: Вообще правильнее смотреть в даташиты от Intel и AMD , но лень искать :)